# Selenium WebDriver Click Sign here (dynamic id) on DocuSign document

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, docusignapi

I need help clicking this dynamic id in a docuSign Document.  Here is the code that will get you to the docuSign document I just need to know how to click the Sign Here image (on the 2nd page) because the id is always different for every signature.  The URL to test docuSign is  https://www.docusign.com/demo.  Here is the @Test I am trying to perform:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class DocusignDemo {

WebDriver driver;
final String url = "https://www.docusign.com/demo";
final String firstName = "first_name";
final String lastName = "last_name";
final String email = "email";
final String phNumber = "phone";
final String jobTitle = "title";
final String company = "company";
final String signItNowButton = "submit_trial_form";
final String reviewDocButton = "ds_hldrBdy_dlgStart_startReview_btnInline";

@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void docuSign() {
    driver.get(url);
    sendKeys(firstName, "First");
    sendKeys(lastName, "Last");
    sendKeys(email, "first@last.com");
    sendKeys(phNumber, "555-555-5555");
    sendKeys(jobTitle, "Job");
    sendKeys(company, "Company");
    clickIt(signItNowButton);
    clickIt(reviewDocButton);
    /*
     * How do I click the Sign here image because the id is dynamic and
     * keeps changing"
     */
}

public void sendKeys(String idX, String keys) {

    driver.findElement(By.id(idX)).sendKeys(keys);
}

public void clickIt(String idX) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(idX)));

    driver.findElement(By.id(idX)).click();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@tabtype='SignHere']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call it by its class?

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign Here")).click();
```

Comment: Wrong button, it's on the next page.